# Adding type signature to where statement causes error I don't understand

Tags: haskell

I'm working on a complicated function in yesod.  It has a lot of functions in the where portion that are untyped, but typecheck properly.  I decided to try and add a few type signatures so that I could figure out what was going on one piece at a time, but adding the type signatures caused type errors.

So I pared down the function to a simple case to post here, which still gives a similar error that I don't understand.

```
helper :: [(String, a)] -> [(Int, a)]
helper xs = blah
  where
    blah :: [(Int, a)]
    blah = zip [1..10] (map snd xs)
```

If I remove the type signature from blah, it compiles just fine, but if I add that type signature it gives me the error:

```
Couldn't match type `a' with `a1'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for helper :: [(String, a)] -> [(Int, a)]
      at Blah.hs:4:1
  `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for blah :: [(Int, a1)] at Blah.hs:7:5
Expected type: [(String, a1)]
  Actual type: [(String, a)]
In the second argument of `map', namely `xs'
In the second argument of `zip', namely `(map snd xs)'
```

1. I also have no idea why the "a" in helper is interpretted as a different "a" than helper when typechecking goes forth.
2. Why it even cares if the a's are different in the first place
3. I have no idea how to figure out what type blah actually is, because I can't move it to the toplevel while still using its argument.

**Edit:**

Okay, I have one more edit before I mark this answered.  In the code I'm using there are some constraints (Eq a, Monad monad) => etc, etc, etc. and so the solution I have doesn't quite work.  So I'm modifying my sample code to be more close to the real code:

```
helper :: (Eq a, Num b) => b -> [(String, a)] -> (b, [(Int, a)])
helper b xs = (b+b, blah)
  where
    blah :: [(Int, a)]
    blah = filter (\y -> fst y == 11) $ zip [1..10] (map snd xs)
```

If I put

```
helper :: forall a. (Eq a, Num b) => b -> [(String, a)] -> (b, [(Int, a)])
```

this doesn't work because (I assume because b is not in scope, but I can't figure out the syntax to get forall b into this type.  (forall a, forall b doesn't work, forall a,b doesn't work).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `a` in the type of `blah` is not the same as the `a` in the type of `helper`, unless you use the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension. So your type signatures are saying that they are independent, but they are clearly not. 
Your code is equivalent to this:

```
helper :: forall a. [(String, a)] -> [(Int, a)]
helper xs = blah
  where
    blah :: forall b. [(Int, b)]
    blah = zip [1..10] (map snd xs)
```

Here you are saying that for any given `a`, we can choose any `b`, but that's not true. Since `xs` has type `[(String, a)]`, `map snd xs` has type `[a]`. So `a` and `b` must be the same type, i.e. `a ~ b`. Thus the compiler complains that `blah` isn't as polymorphic as you said it was in the type signature.

You have three options:

- Remove the type signature. The compiler will infer the correct type for `blah`.
- Enable `ScopedTypeVariables`. The compiler will then realise that you wanted the `a` in the type of `blah` to be the same as the `a` in the signature of `helper`. In this case, you need to add an explicit `forall a.` to the type signature of `helper`:

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
  helper :: forall a. [(String, a)] -> [(Int, a)]
  helper xs = blah
    where
      blah :: [(Int, a)]
      blah = zip [1..10] (map snd xs)
  ```
- Make the type of `blah` independent:

  ```
  helper :: [(String, a)] -> [(Int, a)]
  helper xs = blah xs
    where
      blah :: [(String, b)] -> [(Int, b)] -- Or 'a'. Doesn't matter.
      blah ys = zip [1..10] (map snd ys)
  ```

  Now `blah` will work on any `b`. The fact that you only use it with `b ~ a` is perfectly fine.

**Answer to edit:**

Use a space between the type variables in the `forall`, e.g.

```
helper :: forall a b. (Eq a, Num b) => ...
```

Comment: The only option that works for me, Adding {-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #- to the top of the file, does not get rid of the error.  Still exactly the same.

Comment: @onmach: My bad, you also need an explicit `forall`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This *almost* works.  But I can't quite use this answer yet, so I edited the op.

Comment: @onmach: It should be `forall a b.`. No comma, just a space between the type variables you're quantifying.

Comment: Edit: Actually it does work.  Thanks a lot I can now debug in piece.